# Endless loop in batch file using 'goto'

Tags: batch-file, goto

Well, I have this problem with a little program that I'm making because my loop is endless. Right now I'm trying to use goto command but it doesn't work couse it is endless. Anyone please help.

```
@echo off
color 1a
:i
echo Hi, mate Let's start off by getting each others names.
timeout 5 > nul
echo What is your name ?: 
set /p name=
echo Hi noob %name% my name is Youke 
timeout 2 > nul
echo %name% We are going on an advenutre quest today :D
timeout 2 > nul
goto i
```

Comment: What's the code intention? What is the goto purpose?

Comment: The purpose of the goto is actually nothing it's something i wan't to try out on my programming skills in notepad.

Comment: If it has no purpose, why is it there? Your code loops endlessly because you *told* it to with the `goto`.

Comment: `goto` means " go to " ...

Comment: I'm using this little program as my testing program to test all my new stuff i only want to know how to add a loop that isn't endless.

Comment: then why don't you ask so? `for /L` is your friend. Or if you want to do it "the hard way", use a counter and jump with `if %count% lss 15 goto ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere between the `i` label on line 3 and the `goto` command, you need to add code that will break out of the loop—likely an `if` statement with another `goto` inside it that points to a label after your current `goto`.

You can see plenty of examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711984/436282