# Batch File Nested For /L Loops and Exiting them

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set list=A B C D E

FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
    start %%a.exe > ouput_%%a.txt
    echo 120, 30 second loops = 60 min
    FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,120) DO (
        REM pause for 30 seconds
        ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 > nul

        echo find the running executable
        tasklist | findstr %%a.exe > nul
        REM !ERRORLEVEL!
        REM exit the script if no executable is found (i.e it has run successfully)
        if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 1 goto success
   )
   REM kill executable if we haven't exited yet
   taskkill /f /im %%a.exe
   :success
)
```

This code doesn't go through the for loops as I expect them to. I tried to do something like this [How to break inner loop in nested loop batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710552/how-to-break-inner-loop-in-nested-loop-batch-script) , but to no avail. Any advice?

**EDIT**

ERRORLEVEL is not 1 when an executable has finished running.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set list=A B C D E

FOR %%a IN (%LIST%) DO (
    start %%a.exe > ouput_%%a.txt
    REM 120, 30 second loops = 60 min
    call :innerloop %%a
    REM kill executable if we haven't exited yet
    taskkill /f /im %%a.exe
)
goto :eof
:innerloop
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,120) DO (
    REM pause for 30 seconds
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 > nul

    REM find the running executable
    tasklist | findstr %%a.exe > nul
    REM !ERRORLEVEL!
    REM exit the script if no executable is found (i.e it has run successfully)
    if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 goto :next
)
:next
goto :eof
```

Comment: In your EDITed code, you need to use `!ERRORLEVEL!` rather than `%ERRORLEVEL%`! Furthermore, you are not at all querying `!ERRORLEVEL! in the outer `for` loop. You could test if `call :innerloop %%a || taskkill /f /im %%a.exe` works (meaning `taskkill` is _only_ executed if `call` returns a non-zero `ERRORLEVEL`).

Answer (score 2):

Executing the `goto` command within a `for` loop breaks up the loop iteration. This is true for *all* nested `for` loops.

However, what you can do is moving your inner `for` loop into a sub-routine (call it using `call`). This loop can be terminated by a `goto` command, but after returning from the sub-routine, the remaining (outer) `for` loop is not affected and continues iteration.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set list=A B C D E

FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
    start %%a.exe > ouput_%%a.txt
    echo 120, 30 second loops = 60 min
    REM kill executable if we haven't exited yet
    call :SUBLOOP %%a.exe && taskkill /f /im %%a.exe
)
exit /B

:SUBLOOP
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,120) DO (
    REM pause for 30 seconds
    timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK > nul
    echo find the running executable
    tasklist | findstr /I /B "%~1" > nul
    REM !ERRORLEVEL! is 0 if found and 1 otherwise
    REM exit the script if no executable is found
    REM (i.e it has run successfully)
    if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 1 goto :EOF
)
exit /B 0
```

Herein I moved the inner `for` loop into a sub-routine `:SUBLOOP`, which is called from its former code section by `call :SUBLOOP %%a.exe`, passing the current value to process (the executable `%%a.exe`) from the outer `for` loop to it. `ERRORLEVEL` is transferred to the calling routine upon termination.
After returning from `:SUBLOOP` back to the outer `for` loop, it is checked whether or not `ERRORLEVEL` is zero, and if so, the process of the currently iterated executable is killed. The `&&` is a conditional command separator which executes the second command only if the first one succeeded, that is, if `ERRORLEVEL` is cleared.
Note the `exit /B` command after the outer `for` loop which is necessary to not execute the `SUBLOOP` section unintentionally after the outer loop has been completed.

**Note:**
`goto` does not terminate the `for` loop iteration immediately; in fact every pending iteration is still counted silently, but no more commands of the `for` body are executed. A loop with a huge number of iterations can therefore take a considerable amount of time before batch execution continues. Thank you @foxidrive for this [useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214744/batch-file-nested-for-l-loops-and-exiting-them/32215198#comment52318496_32215198)!
Moreover, if the `goto` target label is placed within the `for` body, execution continues at that point after total completion of the loop. Any code following that point is then treated as "normal" one not part of a `for` body.

Comment: This code is causing the executables to overlap each other if one is still running.

Comment: Sorry one last thing. When adding the `/WAIT` switch `output_%%a.txt` does not have any text inside of it. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Also why do I need the `/WAIT`? The inner for loop is there in order to not allow the outer loop to run until an hour has passed or the executable has finished executing. @aschipfl

Comment: I agree, `/WAIT` sould not be required... I just [corrected an issue](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32215198/4) in `:SUBLOOP` (there was `%2` instead of `%1` erroneously)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87937/discussion-between-emilk-and-aschipfl).

Comment: @aschipfl A `goto` command doesn't immediately terminate a for loop - it silently counts every pass that is yet to go.   Try a `for loop` counting up to 10 million and use a goto when it gets to 5000 to see what happens.

Comment: @foxidrive, let's say it that way: `goto` breaks `for` and makes its variable (for instance `%%a`) non-accessible; for the batch script execution `for` looks terminated;

Comment: @aschipfl  yes, it stops processing the commands - but you wrote `loop immediately terminates iteration` and it doesn't, because a long loop could keep running for 15 more minutes etc before continuing the batch script.  Your description should be reworded to say that a loop can conceivably take considerable time before the batch continues.  There are techniques to immediately exit a `for loop` but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Please see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32215198/5), @foxidrive; I hope everything is correct now; thank you for the very interesting information!

Comment: @emilk, I edited the code (twice actually, see [rev6](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32215198/6) and [rev7](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32215198/7)); summary of changes: 1. I used the wrong separator `||` instead of `&&`; 2. `findstr` now works case-**in**sensitive (like `start`); 3. I replaced `ping` by `timeout` which is intended for delays (if you're working on Windows XP you'll need to go back to your `ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000`);