# Nesting for /f in a for /d batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that runs through several folders in a for /d listing and then echoes the oldest file in the folder.  Ultimately, this will be used to move files to another folder.  The problem I have is I can't get the for /f to escape without ending the entire command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set basefolder=M:\somefolder\*
for /D %%D in (%basefolder%) do (

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR %%D\* /B /O:-D') DO echo "%%I" & goto moved
:moved
)
```

This get me ") was unexpected"

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set basefolder=M:\somefolder\*
for /D %%D in (%basefolder%) do (

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR %%D\* /B /O:-D') DO echo "%%I" & exit /b
)
```

This, of course, exits the command at the first folder that processed.

Can someone suggest something that might actually work?

Comment: yes that's a big issue with batch files: exit exits all the loops, not only the inner one. And `goto` does the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File Nested For /L Loops and Exiting them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214744/batch-file-nested-for-l-loops-and-exiting-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /D %%D in (%basefolder%) do (
 set "show=Y"    
 FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR %%D\* /B /O:-D') DO if defined show (
  echo "%%I"
  set "show="
 )
)
```

Using the fact that `cmd` uses the current value of a variable for `if defined`.

Note that labels cannot be used within a code-block (parenthesised series of commands)

Comment: That is what I'm looking for.  Thank you.