# Renaming certain files with Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Using a batch file is there a way that I can strip off the .failed extension for first 1000 files from all files in a directory.

For example

1.pdf.failed => 1.pdf 2.pdf.failed => 2.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "the first 1000"? the oldest ones?

Comment: I mean,top 1000 in the folder.

Comment: The "top 1000" makes only sense if you provide information about the used sort order (by name, age, size,...)!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
FOR %%f IN (*.pdf.failed) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"
```

If you want to do it only for XX first files, define a variable count and increment it on each loop itineration. When the number is reached, break the loop. 
See how to break the loop here : [How to break inner loop in nested loop batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710552/how-to-break-inner-loop-in-nested-loop-batch-script)

Comment: Have to do it for first 1000 files only